# uncrop graph image with pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

To start, I'm using pycharm pro, which only shows `plt.show()` in image form. I'm making a bar graph where each column has a very long name, and so they have to be vertical. However, right now only a couple letters of each name show up before they are cropped from the graph that is displayed(attached). I've tried `plt.set_margins()` and `plt.autoscale()`, to no avail. What can I do to expand the bottom side of this graph so that at least some words of each column name are visible? Another option would be to make each  column wide enough to fit some of the name horizontally. I'm assuming this is an easy solution becasue I don't know a lot about pyplot.

Thanks[image]

Comment: maybe `plt.tight_layout()`

Comment: you can also consider rotating the labels by 45 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 possibilities

1. Make manual adjustments, as shown in the official docs under [Rotating custom tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_rotation.html#rotating-custom-tick-labels) (I have NOT written the code below)

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
   y = [1, 4, 9, 6]
   labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Bogs', 'Slogs']

   plt.plot(x, y)
   # You can specify a rotation for the tick labels in degrees or with keywords.
   plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
   # Pad margins so that markers don't get clipped by the axes
   plt.margins(0.2)
   # Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of tick-labels
   plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
   plt.show()
   ```

   [image]
2. Use [`plt.tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html)  before `plt.show()`
3. Instantiate the figure using [*constrained_layout*](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html)

   ```
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(..., constrained_layout=True)
   ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks! The manual adjustments worked well enough that I can tell which column is for which response.